# Eigenvalues of an almost skew symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I was plotting the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix $h_2$ continuously transforming into another symmetric matrix, $h_1$, when parameter $\alpha$ is changed from $0$ to $1$.

$$ h = \alpha h_1\ +\ (1-\alpha)h_2  $$

I generated any real square random matrix (entries have a uniform distribution $\in$ [0,1)) and added its transpose to make it symmetric. Nothing unusual here. But subtracting them will give me anti-symmetric matrices. Now, instead of subtracting exactly the transpose of same matrix, I changed it by a small factor. Say I have two real random matrix $r_1$ and $r_2$

$$h_1 = r_1\ -\ (1.1)(r_1)^{T}$$
$$h_2 = r_2\ -\ (1.1)(r_2)^{T}$$

Some of the eigenvalues are degenerate. But with change of parameter $\alpha$, I started seeing these bubbles, as shown in the figure below. Can anyone explain the math behind these? To be precise, I am plotting the real values of eigenvalues with $\alpha$.

To make it more concrete, I have added 3D plot of locus of eigenvalues for $2\times2$ dimension. x and y axis represent real and imaginary coordinates of the eigenvalues and z axis shows $\alpha$. [image: locus on complex plane]

[image: Real values vs alpha]

[image: Imag values vs alpha]

In case, someone wants too check the python code I am using, here is the github [link](https://github.com/quantummonk/pythonBubble/blob/master/bubble.py).

[image: Eigenvalues with alpha]

Comment: Yes, thanks. My bad. It should be transpose of r_1 in the second one. That is what I have used in the program. Forgot to mention it here.

Comment: This has the potential to be a very interesting question, but needs some work. You provided on details on the random matrices. Bernoulli random matrices? Gaussian random matrices? What is the distribution of the entries? IID?

Comment: I just used python's numpy.random.rand(n,n). It seems to have a uniform distribution in range [0,1) I guess.

Comment: It seems? You guess? How long does it take to consult the NumPy documentation and be sure? If you don't put effort in writing your question, you cannot expect anyone to put effort in writing an answer.

Comment: It is a uniform distribution. I am sorry. I am sure.

Comment: Such information should be included in the question. Are you acquainted with [root locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_locus) analysis?

Comment: No, I am not acquainted with that. But I will take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: It's not the same. In root locus, the parameter goes from $0$ to $\infty$ and the eigenvalues travel on the complex plane, occasionally colliding and forming interesting shapes.

Comment: I understand that somehow the 'almost skew symmetric' condition has something to do with these roots of characteristic polynomial evolving in such a manner, but I never thought there will be these bubbles.

Comment: @Rahul, in the range $[0,1)$, the roots are already real. I see the roots are symmetric about the x-axis and closing in as $\alpha \rightarrow 1$, but the bubbles I am getting are not symmetric around x-axis, like parts of some complex-conjugate roots. What was your point? I missed it, I guess.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, you are right. It is not the same, but these are also locus of roots. Maybe I can try to see how the locus looks in 3D by adding imaginary axis as well. I will update how the locus looks there.